# Problems with cast, won't load the sended url

Tags: android, casting

I have a problem with an app on Android, I have set everything right because it works with other urls, but with a certain url doesn't work (even if it works on the iOS app with the same data)
Is there a possible way to see the output log after the url is sent on cast, logs if there are problems with the codecs/decription or stream ?

Also, the cast id is valid and the url is valid because it runs in my video view.

Thanks in advance